# What is the best suited http status code for max limit reached for a given user

Tags: http-status-codes

I have a use case where a user can share his trip through a URL and this particular trip is allowed to generate only 10 different URL in the system. In case user tends to create 11th URL, I have to send the message that

> location sharing with the trip has reached max count of **10**

I looked on the internet for this and found a status code `429`, relating to indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting"). But this is confusing me with rate limiting and resource limiting(request is served only a given number of time).

Hence not able to decide, need the advice or solution to proceed.

Comment: 429 seems appropriate

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the concept of too many web requests within a certain period, and some business logic on your back-end which does not give the ability to the user to perform that action anymore. I believe you should return a 400 error (bad request) with the error message of your choice to display to the user